# Android; How does the manageQuery work in 2.2?

Tags: android, contacts, android-2.2-froyo

I'm trying to display contact information, and from another question on stackOverflow I've got the following snippet

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DISPLAY_NAME
     };

    Uri contacts =  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI;
    //id of the Contact to return.
    long id = 3;

    //Make the query. 
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(contacts,
                                        projection, // Which columns to return 
                                        null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
                // Selection arguments (with a given ID)
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts._ID = "id", 
                // Put the results in ascending order by name
                                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

It seems that the managedQuery has been changed in 2.2 (I belive the original question where I got this was referenced to 2.0)

What has changed in 2.2? I can't find a way of displaying emails, phone numbers etc for a contact

EDIT : This is all I can find from the android debugging logs

```
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519): Writing exception to parcel
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI: content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup, calling user: com.example.android.contactmanager, calling package:com.example.android.contactmanager
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at com.android.providers.contacts.LegacyApiSupport.query(LegacyApiSupport.java:1911)
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:4697)
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:150)
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:111)
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
08-24 20:49:51.893: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(519):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the `Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI` does, but I use the `RawContacts.CONTENT_URI`.

So try `Uri contacts =  ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI` or `Uri contacts =  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` should also work.

And leave the `selectionArgs` (4th-argument) if you didn't specify a `selection` (3rd-argument), because they only make sence if a `selection` is given.